# How to autoselect adjacent cells with same color when clicked

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

I've created big "patterns" of multiple rows and columns containing a title in the first row and numbers populated in the remaining rows and columns.
Only the first row is visible and the other rows are grouped.
All different "patterns" are visually separated with different background colors.

Is there a way to select all cells inside a "pattern" with a given color without ungrouping the other rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is possible to do so only manually. press and hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key and do the selection of the rows with mouse clicks on the row's numbers. of course, it needs to be ungrouped.

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately you confirmed there's no way to select adjacent cells without ungrouping first. Thanks anyway !